# MySQL Query to find an average based on some of the data in the table

Tags: mysql

I have a table which (amongst others) has fields dateawarded, beltcolor and users id (userid).

beltcolor is 'varchar' and dateawarded is 'date', userid is int.

This data represents the date that students were awarded their various color belts (Brazilian Jiu Jitsu).

What I would like to establish is the average time between belts /  the average time spent at a given belt.

Since purple comes after blue, if I wanted to find out the average time spent on blue, I guess what I need to do is:

for each user id that has a purple belt (not all have made it to purple yet), take the date the the blue belt was awarded and the date the purple belt was awarded and calculate the time between them. Add all the times up and divide by the number of people who were found to have reached purple belt.

Can you help me with a SQL query?

Thanks!
Sean

Answer (score 0):

This is a query to find out the average number of days between purple and blue. You can adapt it to other situations:

```
SELECT AVG(datediff(a.dateawarded,b.dateawarded)) as Average
FROM beltsTable a
INNER JOIN beltsTable b ON a.userid = b.userid
WHERE a.beltcolor = "purple" AND b.beltcolor = "blue"
```

<kbd>[sqlfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/47175/1)</kbd>

This will only take in consideration the users that have both belts. If a user only has a blue belt, it will not be taken in consideration.

Answer (score 0):

First you should find previous belt date for the current belt (see inner query) and then just count AVG of days between current date and previous for each belt color.

[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1b9e4/12)

```
select beltcolor,
       FLOOR(AVG(DATEDIFF(dateawarded,Prev_dateawarded))) as Days_to_reach

from
(

select beltcolor,dateawarded,id,
COALESCE((select MAX(dateawarded) from T
        where id=T1.id 
              and dateawarded<T1.dateawarded) 
  ,dateawarded)
as Prev_dateawarded 
from T as T1
) As T2        

group by beltcolor
```